# Will I be able to bring my baby to the US visa interview?

Tags: visas, usa

My infant daughter is accompanying me to the US on a J visa, from the UK. Will I be allowed to bring her with me to the Visa interview? Or will I need to arrange child-care?

Comment: Are you also applying for a J-2 visa for her?

Comment: Yes I will applying for a J2 for her. My wife is also applying for J2 at the same time.

Comment: Why do you think you can’t take your child with you?

Comment: A colleague told me that they told her to keep her child at home. She thought the reasons was because babies would disturb the interview.

Comment: One possible outcome is they could even fast-track you, letting you skip the whole waiting queue as you're with an infant; at least, I once saw an American consulate do this.

Comment: In case this post is of use for anyone in the future: not only was the baby allowed in the interview, they let us jump all the queues.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd bring her along, especially if she is also applying. We unfortunately found that many US consulates behave quite inconsistently. We had multiple occasions where the information provided during the appointment process: "no problem, your kids do not need to be here" turned out to be irrelevant during the actual visit "no, I can't do this, because your kids are not here".

In one case we actually got a written appointment confirmation that explicitly stated that the kids did not need to be physically present. However, the confirmation letter arrived two weeks after the actual appointment, so it didn't help.

It's unclear whether the consulate have any set of rules or guidelines for kid's being present, but even if they do, they often won't follow them or just make it up on the fly, and there is nothing you can do about it.

Your best bet is to be as prepared as possible: bring all family members and any conceivable documention (birth certificates, driver's licence, a few utility bills, letters/communication with the school, attorney, etc.)

Comment: Thank you!  My question now seems a little silly in hindsight. I was more concerned that they'd say "that infant is too disruptive and cannot come in the interview room" in which case I'll have no where to put a 3 month old baby.

Comment: Perhaps the safest course of action is to take the child with your, as well as another non-applying friend or family member who can care for her should the interviewer not desire her presence.

Comment: Plus if you have a crying baby they bump you up the queue.

Comment: @Mehrdad: unfortunately this was one of the more harmless things, US consulates have done to us over the years. I have plenty of example of unprofessional, incompetent, or plain old mean behavior.